# Javascript: match variable name and apply to matched variable

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I want to have a function that can auto match the variable name inside of an object and apply them to the local variable if the name matched.

I am currently using this way, but as the variable increasing I want to actually make a new function to apply them.

```
ob = { a: 1, b: 2, }

-----------------------------

Install(ob)

function Install(ob){
  if('a' in ob) a = ob.a;
  if('b' in ob) b = ob.b;
}

var a; var b;
```

I want something can do like this

```
function Install(ob){
  for( // each ob`s this varaiable name){     
    if (//this name much local variable name){
     //local varaible = ob this variable 
     }
  }
}
```

Is this possible? Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this code? why do you need a variable `a` when you can just refer to `ob.a` ?

Comment: because I have a lot of variables......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make top level global variables out of all properties of an object (which I'm unsure why you would do), you can do that like this:

```
var ob = {a: 1, b: 2};
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) {
        window[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
}
```

Otherwise, please explain better what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. If I say I have 26 variables from a to z, doing this is a faster and better..Or is there any alternative I can look at?

Comment: @Till - it is unclear why you're trying to change properties of an object into global variables.  Generally, it is best practice to avoid global variables as much as possible and putting a group of like variables on an object is often the best alternative so none of us understand why you're trying to undo the best practice.

Comment: all these are the variables can be designed in local or inside of a function, or I can switch window[prop] to var obj2[prop] .....I just want to know the way how to match the variable names...

Comment: @Till - sorry, I don't understand that comment/question.  There is no way to use a `window[prop]` like syntax to address local variables (there is no root object for local variables) and there's no reason to turn an object's properties into local variables either.  Just access them on the object.

Comment: no, I mean I can use another ob instead of window..If I set the ob2 and install function inside a function, and New = new Old(), then New.install(ob)...That is local

Comment: @Till - we could help you a lot better if you'd explain what problem you're actually trying to solve.  You can substitute any other object instead of `window` in that code.  That just changes the function into a shallow copy that copies properties from one object to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign variables from object to window like this.

```
function Install(ob) {
    for (var i = 0, keys = Object.keys(ob), l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
        window[keys[i]] = ob[keys[i]];
    }
}
```

And later access it simple `console.log(varname)`. But you doing smth strange ;)

Comment: FYI, `Object.keys()` does not exist on IE 8 or before and isn't required to iterate the properties of an object.